# Long[] cannot be converted to String[]

Tags: android, string, sqlite, long-integer

I wanted to update my `SQLite` data but I get  `incompatible types: Long[] cannot be converted to String[]` error.

```
public void Update(long id, String name, String weather, String date, String status )
    {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        Long [] args={id};
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Name, name);
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather, weather);
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Date, date);
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Status, status);
        database.update(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, cv, MyDatabaseHelper.ID + "= ?",args);}
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks

Comment: @sourabhbans it's not about datatype in id. `database.update` only accept array of string in 4th parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can just do it like this :

```
public void Update(long id, String name, String weather, String date, String status )
    {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Name, name);
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather, weather);
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Date, date);
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Status, status);
        database.update(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, cv, MyDatabaseHelper.ID + "=" + id,null);
    }
```

OR

Convert your id to string :

```
public void Update(long id, String name, String weather, String date, String status )
    {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        String [] args={String.valueOf(id)};
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Name, name);
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather, weather);
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Date, date);
        cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Status, status);
        database.update(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, cv, MyDatabaseHelper.ID + "= ?",args);
    }
```